# Why doesn't this signal fire?

Tags: python, django

I have a signal for post or pre delete I'm not sure which to use, but my question is, why doesn't this signal activate?  It never saves the files in the directory.  It just does nothing.

Here is the code:

```
@receiver(post_delete, sender=ClientUpload)
def clientupload_postdelete(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    filename = os.path.basename(instance.file_upload.path)
    client = instance.file.client
    if instance.file_upload:
        copyfile(instance.file_upload.path, settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/uploads/Recycle/' + client + '/' + filename)  
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.info("File %s moved to %s" % (filename, settings.MEDIA_ROOT + 'uploads/Recycle/'))

        # Pass False so FileField doesn't save the model.
        instance.file_upload.delete(False)
    else:
        logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
        logger.warning("Failed to find file %s for copying to %s." % (filename, settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/uploads/Recycle/'))
```

Here is the model ClientUpload:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class ClientUpload(models.Model):

    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    file_upload = models.FileField(upload_to=generate_filename)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.client.company

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = _("Client Uploads")
        verbose_name = _("Client Upload")
```

Any idea why it isn't working? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you post the code that is used to delete`ClientUpload` object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you registering the signal handler? Annotating the function with the `receiver` decorator alone isn't enough. Here's how you would do that assuming you are defining the handler function in `signals.py`:

```
my_awesome_project/
|-- my_awesome_app/
|   |-- __init__.py   <-- set default_app_config here
|   |-- apps.py       <-- define your AppConfig subclass here
|   |-- signals.py    <-- define your signal handling functions here
|-- other_app/
|-- my_awesome_project/
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- settings.py
    |-- wsgi.py
```

**apps.py**

```
from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAwesomeAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name="my_awesome_app"

    def ready(self):
        from . import signals
```

**__init__.py**

```
default_app_config = 'my_awesome_app.apps.MyAwesomeAppConfig'
```

From the [Django 1.8 docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/#connecting-receiver-functions):

> In practice, signal handlers are usually defined in a signals
>   submodule of the application they relate to. Signal receivers are
>   connected in the `ready()` method of your application configuration
>   class. **If you’re using the `receiver()` decorator, simply import the
>   signals submodule inside `ready()`.**

**EDIT:**

Subclassing `AppConfig` and importing your separate `signals` module in the `ready` method isn't required to get signals working; it is a best practice to avoid the same signal handler getting connected more than once as Django starts. What I've shown isn't the only way to connect your signal handlers but it is the recommended way.

Comment: I was putting it in models.py.  I'm sort of confused by your answer.  So in my app folder (same folder as models, views, etc.) I put apps.py with that class and add that config line to the __init__.py in that same folder?  I am only using the receiver decorator.  Would I just do that import you have there after adding my signal to signals.py from models.py where it is now?  I don't see how this is registering the signal handler.

Comment: Not sure how but before I was able to implement that it began to work.  Without registering or anything.  That is when I delete from the admin interface, I still am having trouble with my dashboard delete view so I can't test it there yet.  But why is it working without registering it as you said was needed?

Comment: @shenk Yes, the `apps.py` goes into the app folder and the `__init__.py` you edit is the one in the root of that app. I'll update the folder structure to show the entire project.